# How to use big numbers in the vertex shader using WebGL

Tags: webgl, precision

How to use big numbers in the vertex shader? My vertex shader code is

```
        const vertexShaderCode = `
            attribute vec3 vertexPos;
            uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
            uniform vec3 transPos;
                uniform bool isFlat;
                uniform vec2 mapWH;
                uniform vec2 scrWH;
                void main(void) {
                            float normalizedX = ( vertexPos.x - transPos.x) / mapWH.x;
                            float normalizedY = ( vertexPos.y - transPos.y) / mapWH.y;
                            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vec4(normalizedX * scrWH.x, (1.0 - normalizedY) * scrWH.y, 0.0, 1.0);
            }
                `
```

My vertexPos values approximately 17 million, transPos values are around 16 million, and mapWH values are approximately 200. When these values are like this, the line I draw on the screen flickers due to floating-point precision. I have to use WebGL1. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Good question; usually you try to avoid this situation at all costs. As you said, WebGL 1 only has 32 bit `float` precision and those numbers really are large enough to cause problems. I think I had a similar issue, with similar numbers, and I know what you are probably seeing on screen. The trick, generally speaking, is to try to do the big computations on the CPU, in Javascript, using its 64-bit support. You must preprocess the data so that that everything is smaller: attribute data, and uniform data. How exactly depends on your case. Are you doing geographical rendering? Or a flight sim?

Comment: There is also another strategy where you keep all the logic in the shader but you use "multiple" `float`s to emulate 64-bit precision that in reality you don't have on the GPU. If you do this, there is a chance that you can keep the Javascript code the way it is, and you only have to change the GLSL code. But I don't have much experience with this approach. For the other approach, the CPU based one, if you provide more details I can definitely try to help.

Comment: Hello, I have a 2d map like leaflet, the metric values of the world in the mercator projection at the minimum (longitude: -180, latitude:-85) and maximum (longitude: 180, latitude:85) latitude and longitude values -20037508.34 and 20037508.34. I have to use such values in the shader in the shader. The line I draw with this type of coordinates flickers

Comment: Makes sense, I see those kind of numbers every day. I recommend that you give it a shot at pre-processing the coordinates and transformation matrices on the CPU. Here is an example. Disclaimer: it's the website of my employer and I am the author of the article: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/custom-gl-visuals/#dealing-with-precision-issues . In your specific case, you would need to break the line into multiple segments, each one rendered by a different draw call. Other frameworks do everything on the GPU as you described: https://deck.gl/docs/developer-guide/fp64

Comment: The technique in the first article that I linked is good enough in most cases, but you can improve on it by including also a scale factor. See also https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/js-api-arcgis/developers/jumpstart-your-custom-layer/ paragraph Benefit #2: Simplified view state management. Consider that, in order to handle multiple level of details, which is often the case for maps, some sort of CPU-side processing is needed so you may as well focus on that.